# Virtualbox - Android x86 VMs crashing after update to 18.04

Tags: virtualbox, android

for testing purposes I often use Android x86 VMs in Virtualbox (I know they're not officially supported, but they work fine). Until recently, I had Virtualbox 5.1.34 and Ubuntu (Mate) 17 and everything worked fine.

Now I performed an update of my distro from 17 to 18.04 and together with that, Virtualbox updated to 5.2.10.

Whenever I want to run an Android x86 VM (I don't have any other systems), it boots (or loads when I run it from a restored snapshot) fine but after a few seconds it crashes (the window closes and the state of the VM in the menu is **Aborted**). This happens to my old VMs as well as some new VMs I tried to make.

I tried to read the log of a VM that crashed, but I don't really understand what to look for. I pasted it here on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KX8pJLhY). The log is from Android 6.0 (64bit) that booted normally (no snapshot).

I tried to downgrade my Virtualbox back to 5.1.34, but `apt-cache showpkg virtualbox` says that the only version available for my system is 5.2.10. After trying to downgrade manually, Virtualbox complains that some kernel modules have a wrong version and I cannot fix it.

Is there anything I can do to get my VMs working? Or do I just have to wait for an update for Virtualbox and hope it's going to solve my problem?